# Is there a difference regarding battery between Apple Watch 38 mm and 42 mm?

Tags: ios, battery, apple-watch

Apple says [here](http://www.apple.com/watch/compare/) the battery power for all Apple Watches no matter which size is up to 18 hours.

But is there a difference regarding battery? The 42mm version has bigger display, maybe also a bigger battery? Is there any difference? I would like to buy the device with the best battery.

Comment: Remember that a larger screen used more battery.

Comment: Yes. But as long as you do not exaggerate with push 42 mm should still be the better choice. I think most consumption will be app / background activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple used to say that the larger Apple Watch ‘typically experiences longer battery life’ on their [Apple Watch battery information page](http://www.apple.com/watch/battery.html), however they removed this line from the page when the Apple Watch Series 2 was released.

The mAh specifications are as follows:

- Apple Watch (original) & Apple Watch **Series 1, 38mm: 205 mAh** [(source)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7593669)
- Apple Watch (original) & Apple Watch **Series 1, 42mm: 246 mAh** [(source)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7593669)
- Apple Watch **Series 2, 38mm: 273 mAh** [(source)](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Apple+Watch+Series+2+Teardown/67385)
- Apple Watch **Series 2, 42mm: 334 mAh** [(source)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Watch_Series_2)